# How to highlight selected <li> item only?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to learn web designing and when trying to add class into it through java script ran into trouble.

html code:

```
<ul>
    <li onclick="switchChannel(channel1)>
        #Channel1
    </li>
    <li onclick="switchChannel(channel2) class="selected">
        #Channel2
    </li>
    <li onclick="switchChannel(channel3)>
        #Channel3
    </li>
```

css code:

```
.selected{
    color:blue;
    border-left:4px solid blue;
}
```

javascript:script.js

```
function switchChannel(channelName) {
    }
```

javascript:channel.js

```
    var channel1={
        name:"Channel1",
        createdOn:new Date("April 1, 2016"),
        starred:false
};

     var channel2={
            name:"Channel1",
            createdOn:new Date("April 1, 2016"),
            starred:false
    };
```

I want to be able to click a channel1 from the list and apply .selected class to it but when channel2 is clicked remove .selected from channel1 and apply it to channel2 and so on...

If I have messed up anything else in the code please feel free to comment on it.

Comment: why is the script.js empty?

Comment: @Sv443 that's the part you are supposed to write for him ;)

Comment: why are you missing `"`?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_add_class.asp

Comment: I use the `event.target` of the click event to get the <li> item, that was clicked. So if you save the element that is clicked every time, you can remove the class from that element, before you overwrite that variable with the new target you just highlighted. PS: the name of your second channel is also Channel1, so you ahve duplicate names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of answers here but they don't seem to be addressing the actual issue. Here is a quick example using vanilla JavaScript to accomplish what you are asking for.

```js
function switchChannel(el){
  // find all the elements in your channel list and loop over them
  Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('ul[data-tag="channelList"] li')).forEach(function(element){
    // remove the selected class
    element.classList.remove('selected');
  });
  // add the selected class to the element that was clicked
  el.classList.add('selected');
}
```

```css
.selected{
    color:blue;
    border-left:4px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<!-- Add the data-tag attribute to this list so you can find it easily -->
<ul data-tag="channelList">
    <li onclick="switchChannel(this)">Channel 1</li>
    <li onclick="switchChannel(this)" class="selected">Channel 2</li>
    <li onclick="switchChannel(this)">Channel 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `getElementsById`and `getElementsbyTagName`to manipulate the DOM:

```js
function selectChannel(channelNumber) {
  let listItems = document.getElementById("items").getElementsByTagName("li");
  var length = listItems.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    listItems[i].className = i+1 == channelNumber ? "selected" : "";
  }
}
```

```css
.selected {
  color: blue;
  border-left: 4px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<ul id="items">
  <li onclick="selectChannel(1)">#channel1</li>
  <li onclick="selectChannel(2)" class="selected">#channel2</li>
  <li onclick="selectChannel(3)">#channel3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This will only work if there is only 1 class assigned to the items, you should probably access the `classList` and add or remove the class via the add and remove methods.

Comment: Granted, however it's merely an example, and the point of the example is to show to handle this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses jQuery but I thought this might help you out. A CodePen showing a version of this in action can be seen [here](https://codepen.io/susanwinters/pen/avaNKJ).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('li').click(function(event){
        //remove all pre-existing active classes
        jQuery('.selected').removeClass('selected');

        //add the active class to the link we clicked
        jQuery(this).addClass('selected');     
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: While this does address the question there was no mention of jQuery so it might not be available. Also `event.preventDefault()` might not be applicable here and cause undesired side effects.

Comment: I was leaving this up the user to let me know if this was beneficial or not to them, my goal was to possibly help them find a soltuion and if not atleast point them in the right directions to achieving the it. @AdamH

Comment: Your help is appreciated however you might have wanted to check with the OP in the comments to see if jQuery was available

Comment: I am using jQuery, sorry for not mentioning it in the beginning, I tried this method but selected class never gets added into newly selected channel.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. And I thank you every for your help.

```
$('li').removeClass('selected');
$('li:contains(' + channelName.name + ')').addClass('selected');
```